# ASP.NET Xml file reading, sorting and selecting optimization

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sorting, paging

I am concerned with the implementation of a web application that needs to show some data from an xml file.

### Scenario

An xml file memorizes data in a way like this:

```
<?xml?>
<Root>
   <Block>
      <Data1>...<Data1>
      <Data2>...<Data2>
      <Data3>...<Data3>
      <Data4>...<Data4>
   </Block>
   <Block>
      <Data1>...<Data1>
      <Data2>...<Data2>
      <Data3>...<Data3>
      <Data4>...<Data4>
   </Block>
   ...
   <Block>
      <Data1>...<Data1>
      <Data2>...<Data2>
      <Data3>...<Data3>
      <Data4>...<Data4>
   </Block>
</Root>
```

Well, consider that this file will grow significantly.

### The problem

When I load my ASP.NET web form, the first thing I must do is paging this file. Well I would need to sort the file and then page it, you all understand that it is impossible to correctly page on sorted file without reading ALL the file (reading all blocks).

### Present solution

In order to sort and page sorted data (I load the xml and data in it is released in a `DataTable`) I get ALL data from the file and fill a `DataTable`, I apply it to a `DataView` specifying sorting options, I sort the table and then I use `MyDataView.ToTable()` in order to get the sorted `DataTable`.

Not a very good approach (consider that I do this everytime the page loads).

### A better solution is required

I would like to optimize this, given that I need to page I have no reason to load the entire file, and then show only a part of it.

In order to ptimize this a little, when I load another page, I should reload all the file and then select only another range of rows in the `DataTable`. Instead of doing so, store the `DataTable` in `ViewState` so that, at least, I do not need to reparse the entire xml file.

But it is still not good.

### A desirable solution

What I would like to do is:

1) Parse the xml file in a "light mode": I mean a mode where I scan all file, but without inspecting it too deeply... just using the first child (`Data1`).

2) Sorting this partial view of the entire data.

3) Getting ids (every block has an id)

4) Re-inspecting the file, deeply, focusing only onto those blocks having the specified ids

### My question

My question is:

1) Can I achieve this desirable solution somehow?

2) Is this a good solution?

3) Are there better approaches to this problem (I think it is a very common one)?

Please remember that my goal is optimizing times for accessing a large xml file to sort and page!

Thankyou

### Notes

1) Xml is required, I cannot use SqlServer or MySql or similar.

Comment: Can you use a database instead of the XML file?

Comment: @Xint0: No sorry... it is a requirement.

Comment: How often does the XML file change?

Comment: @Xint0: The xml file grows significantly in time... It is meant to store much data however do not focus too much in it, what I really want to achieve is finding a good scalable solution in order to satisfy the needs I told about in my question... even if the file does not change so much...
However if you really need this info... I cannot predict how fast it may change, it depends by the throughput... consider every possibility like I am doing.

Answer (score 3):

You might do something like:

```
int min = 10;
int max = 20;
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
IEnumerable<XElement> range = root.Elements("Block")
   .Where(xe =>
   {
      var value = xe.Attribute("Id");
      if(null == value) return false;
      int id = (int)value;
      return id >= min && id <= max;
   });
```

Then store the last min & max values in ViewState.

If the Block Id's are sorted, you'd only need to find the first Id and then get the next several in your range elements you require.